# angular 6, nested parameter with http Post service

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a service which make a POST call `/albums/{id}/songs`.
Below is the api to the Album.

```
POST /albums



  private serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api";
  private albumApi = "/albums";
  private Url = this.serverUrl+this.albumApi;

/** POST: add a new album to the server */
addAlbum(album: Album): Observable<Album> {
  return this.http.post<Album>(this.Url, album, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    tap((album: Album) => this.log(`added Album w/ id=${album.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Album>('addalbum'))
  );
}
```

But I need to post the songs of an album, so I have to get the Album ID first then exec the create

```
POST /albums/{id}/songs
```

How do I get the id and the same time create the Post.

Thank you.

Comment: So cant you replace `this.Url` with ``/albums/${album.id}/songs`` ?

Comment: I tried something like this but not sure**POST: add a new song to album */
addAlbumSong(id: string,albumSong:AlbumSong):Observable<AlbumSong>{
  const url = `${this.Url}/${id}/songs`;
  return this.http.post<AlbumSong>(url,albumSong,httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    tap((albumSong:AlbumSong)=>this.log(`added AlbumSong id=${albumSong.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<AlbumSong>('addAlbumSong'))
  )
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**POST: add a new song to album */
```

addAlbumSong(albumSong:AlbumSong,id:string):Observable{
  const url = `${this.Url}/${id}/songs`;
  return this.http.post(url,albumSong,httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    tap((albumSong:AlbumSong)=>this.log(`added AlbumSong id=${albumSong.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError('addAlbumSong'))
  )
}
  Service

```
  addAlbumSongComp(audio:string,video:string,lyrics:string,name:string,albumId:string):void{  
this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{

  albumId  = params['id'];
  if(!name){return}
this.albumService.addAlbumSong({name,audio,video,lyrics,albumId} as AlbumSong,params['id'])
.subscribe(data=>{
   this.albumsongs.push(data);
  console.log(data);
})
```

})
  }

Component